# NDK-compiled GLES v1 broken on Nexus 5 Android 5 (Lollipop)

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-ndk, android-5.0-lollipop

I have an app on Google Play that's been working fine on Android 4 versions and below, which uses GLES v1 libraries compiled with the Android NDK. When trying this app on a nexus 5 device upgraded to Lollipop, it just displays a black screen. Are there any known issues with Lollipop, NDK and GLES?

Comment: There's a large number of GLES 1 apps on the market, so unless they're all breaking this is probably specific to your app.  Do you have an APK that you know used to work that no longer works?  Or is it just the newly-built form?

Comment: Correct, the APK on Google Play works fine on devices running 4.4 or below, the GLES component just doesn't work on my Nexus 5 running the latest image of Lollipop - I was alerted by a user who commented the same. I thought it might be a binary compatibility issue regarding the NDK-compiled code, but I recompiled with the latest NDK (released this month) and the latest version of Android Tools. Very odd. BTW, I wouldn't put money on it that this isn't happening to others using GLES NDK-compiled code.Google doesn't even have Lollipop share on its deployment stats dashboard yet.

Comment: Well, step 1 is probably replace all of your rendering code with a glClear() call that just makes the screen red.  If you don't see that, it's probably a Surface issue rather than a GLES issue.

Comment: Thanks, appreciated - will investigate further this end.

Comment: have you succeed to fix this problem? i have similar problem with Lollipop and my app which is partially based on openGL 1.x. mainly happen on Adreno S80x devices

Comment: Sorry, nope. Our assumption is that this is a Lollipop problem and the installed base for this version is small enough that this is not a major issue. For our app, it also appears to be an issue with GLES2.